# WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is not enabled warning on Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the warning

WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is not enabled

on an Azure function.

Does anyone know why MS class this as a warning?

Although they provide an explanation, I dont see why this is flagged, because when this option we cannot appear to enable/disable specific functions which could be useful

Am I missing something obvious?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting this warning if you're trying to run your function app from a local package file, and you don't have the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` configuration enabled.

In my case, because I also do ZIP deployments to my function app, I have it like this:

[image]

To get more information regarding this configuration, visit [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#enable-functions-to-run-from-a-package).

When using this deployment mechanism, the azure functions become "READ ONLY" because the app is reading the files directly from the uploaded ZIP, and so there's no way to edit them.

I don't think it's possible to disable a specific function within a function app when doing a package deployment, but you can remove this "READ ONLY" restriction by removing the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` configuration, but be aware that this will also remove all the functions from the function app.

Comment: ok I will check this.  Im unsure about running it from a package though as it doesnt allow us to disable specific function(s)

Comment: When you say you can't disable them, does it mean you have this warning ->  "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file." ?

Comment: yes thats what I mean

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more details. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'Accepted' or give it an upvote, thank you :)